# interleaving floats and strings in java

Tags: java

I need to interleave 2 array of floats , floats, strings and put them in a list.

```
float[] array1;
float[] array2;
float value1;
float value2;
string name1;
string name2;
```

at the output something like:

```
{array1[i], array2[i], "name1", value1, value2, "name2",  value1, value....}
```

is this possible in java?

ok I'm trying this but it wont work:

```
static Object[] dumoToCurve(final float[] x, final float[] y)   {
    final Object[] output = new Object[x.length * 2];
    float value= 1;

    for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++){

        output[i << 1] = x[i];
        output[(i << 1) + 1] = y[i];
        output[(i << 1) + 2] = "b0";
        output[(i << 1) + 3] = x[i]+value;
        output[(i << 1) + 4] = y[i]+value;
        output[(i << 1) + 5] = "b1";
    }

    return output;
}
```

do I need to cast? how?

Comment: Yes, if you make the array of type `Object[]`. But how do you plan on accessing the elements later?

Comment: thanks, once the array is build up I dont need to modify it.

Comment: It's not about modifying it. But rather how you plan to read it? The type information is lost through the upcast - unless you know what type each element is and will downcast appropriately.

Comment: oh I understand. So we can not read thru the array like normal?

Comment: You can pull it out of the array, but it will be of type `Object`. There isn't much you can do with an `Object` unless you know what type it really is and cast it down.

Comment: I feel lost. I've made a example to show what I want to do..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an answer to your edit. I don't have a Java compiler in front of me to test it. So I'm not completely sure if it will work. Also, I think some of this can be simplified via auto-(un)boxing.

```
for (int i=0; i < x.length; i++){

    output[ i << 1     ] = new Float(x[i]);
    output[(i << 1) + 1] = new Float(y[i]);
    output[(i << 1) + 2] = "b0";
    output[(i << 1) + 3] = new Float(x[i] + value);
    output[(i << 1) + 4] = new Float(y[i] + value);
    output[(i << 1) + 5] = "b1";
}
```

To pull out a `float` value from the array:

```
float val = ((Float)output[0]).floatValue();
```

If the cast fails, it'll give you an exception.

In the end, you might want to consider a different design pattern.

Comment: cool thanks! I get an exception in this lines   output[(i << 1) + 3] = ((Float)x[i]).floatValue() + value;  and output[(i << 1) + 4] = ((Float)y[i]).floatValue() + value;

Comment: this looks good, thanks Mysticial. What do you suggest to improve the design?

Comment: You should probably make two arrays. One for the strings and one for the floats. Trying to mix them into the same array will lead to this mess of casting, boxing/unboxing, etc...

Comment: It will obviously depend on how you intend to use this final (mixed) array. I suppose if you're just gonna call `.toString()` on everything to print it out then it's fine. But if you intend to read the float values back out and perform arithmetic on them, then you'll run into the mess of casting and unboxing.

Comment: btw, looking at your past questions, you probably didn't realize that you can "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer. You should probably do this with all your questions you feel have been answered.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what your data structure represents, but would it be better to model it as a class? For example:

```
// completely made up class
class Player {
  ...
  private float[] latitudeHistory;
  private float[] longitudeHistory;
  private float currentLatitude;
  private float currentLongitude;
  private String playerName;
}
```

Comment: I have two float arrays wich represent the X and Y position of a curve then I need a string ("b0") another X and Y point then again string ("b1") and x y. this structure has a dynamic length. So at the end something like:  { X[i],Y[i], "b0", X[i]-value, X[i]-value, "b1", X[i]+value, X[i]+value ... }  value is a float

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is,
Just put this into array of object

```
Object[] myObjects = new Object[] {array1[i], array2[i], "name1", value1, value2, "name2",  value1, value....};
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup.

Here's an example

```
   int i = 4;
   long j = 323232333;
   String k = "dadasdad";
   char c = 'a';
   Object [] x = {c,i,j,k};

    for( Object z : x){
            System.out.println(z);
    }
```